# 404 error when calling java method

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, ajax, http

I am building Web App with AngularJS and Java.
I am trying to call a java method from angularJS but I am getting 404 error.
Java code:

```
@Stateless
@ApplicationPath("/resources")
@Path("test")
public class RunsResource extends Application {

    @GET
    public Object helloWorld() {
        return say;
    }
}
```

Javascript code:

```
app.controller('runsList', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.hello = function() {
    alert("hihihihihihi");
    $http({
        url : 'resources/test',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        method : 'GET'
    }).success(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Error: "+status);
    });
};
```

When I call the hello function, I am getting the following error:

```
 http://localhost:5140/myapp/resources/test 404 (Not Found)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried with: `http://localhost:5140/resources/test`

And make sure port is 5140

Comment: Check whether your resources are properly mapped in xml files